# Implement data structure with efficient insert/findKthSmallest operations

Tags: arrays, object, data-structures

I was asked this question by an interviewer. I tried solving it using an array, such that I make sure the array in sorted when I insert. However I don't think this is the best solution. What would be a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Balenced Binary Search Tree(eg: red-black bst) for this.

- Simply insert the nodes in the balenced bst. and each node maintains its rank within its own subtree. As we need to find the smallest element we can maintain count of elements in left subtree.
- Now, start traversing from root and check:

  - if k = N +1, where N is number of nodes in roots left subtree. if yes than root is kth node.
  - else if K < N, continue to search in the left subtree of root.
  - else if k > N +1, then continue to search in the right subtree. And search for (K-N-1) smallest element.

**Time complexity** of `insertion` in a balenced bst is O(logn). While searching for kth smallest element will be O(h), where h is height of the tree.

Comment: *"maintain the Rank of each node in the tree"* - how do you do this without updating the rank of potentially every node when you insert a new node with rank 0?

Comment: @kaya3 this can be handled inside our insert function of the tree. The tree node can have a extra property like leftNodeCount and we can update this property of each parent node while traversing and looking for insertion position.

Comment: I see. That's not quite the same as each node maintaining its rank, because every leaf node will store a "rank" of 0, for example. It would be clearer to say that each node maintains its rank within its own subtree.

Comment: @kaya3 updated the answer :-) hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes! I haven't seen an order statistic tree implemented this way before, but it seems to work. By the way, O(*h*) is the same as O(log *n*) since the tree is balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). Essentially, it is a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) where each node also stores the cardinality of its subtree. Maintaining the cardinality does not increase the complexity of any tree operations, but allows your query to be performed in O(log *n*) time:

- If the left subtree has cardinality > *k*, recurse on the left subtree.
- Otherwise, if the left subtree has cardinality < *k*, recurse on the right subtree.
- Otherwise the left subtree's cardinality equals *k*, so return the current node's element.